# Receiving UDP broadcasts on multihomed systems

Tags: windows, udp, broadcast

I have a Windows XP machine with more than one network adapter.  When I receive a UDP broadcast package from another machine that does not yet have a valid IP address, howcan I determine which network adapter received this package?

I need to implement a kind on custom DHCP server...

Answer (score 0):

If the other machine doesn't have an IP address, then I don't think that it can be broadcasting UDP!

Do you mean a 'RARP' broadcast instead of a 'UDP' broadcast?

Comment: Don't think so.  I send UDP broadcasts myself to discover these machines, and they reply back with another UDP broadcast package.  Their IP address is set zo some invalid value (I think).